# I need to read in a file and split it into different columns in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file, timestamp

I don't have much experience using Python and I am trying to read in a log file. So far I am able to read in the file and print it out.

```
infile = open("C:\file.log", "r")
lines = infile.readlines()
print lines
print len(lines)
infile.close()
```

The file contains double values and also a timestamp, for example:

```
08 Apr 2014 00:00:31, 22.198, 5.444, 67.901
08 Apr 2014 00:00:31, 33.198, 6.444, 54.901
08 Apr 2014 00:00:31, 44.198, 5.444, 84.901
08 Apr 2014 00:00:31, 55.198, 8.444, 94.901
```

Each of these values are different measurements, ie. the first number is a timestamp, the second is CPU usage etc. How do I read these in and store each column into a different array??

Comment: Why not to create a dict

Answer (score 2):

```
r = csv.reader(open(filename))
dates = []
times = []
cpus = []
usages = []
for d, t, v1, v2 in r:
    dates.append(d)
    times.append(t)
    cpus.append(float(v1)
    usages.append(v2)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this was great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my preferred way of reading tables. It ends up with one return value and is very short to write.

```
#create a list of keys for each data entry
label_list = ["timestamp", "cpu_usage", "foo", "bar"]
# make a container to hold the entries
data = []
# using with/as is a safer way to open files
with open("C:\file.log", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        # split the element
        value_list = line.split(", ")
        # create a dictionary for each entry, with label_list as keys
        data.append({})
        for value, label in zip(value_list , label_list):
            data[-1][label] = value
# whenever you want a group of items you can do this. ex) cpu_usage
print [d["cpu_usage"] for d in data]
```